# spring-security-aotuh2 offers default endpoints to register clients and application users?

Tags: jpa, client

i was looking at the following example to create an authentication server under spring security framework version 6 and oauth2: https://github.com/wdkeyser02/SpringBootOauth2Server/tree/ClientRegistrationEndpoint
this example implements user and client persistence in jpa, i have seen that spring offers in-memory and jdbc implementation. my question is, as login, logout, etc endpoints, is there any endpoint to create users and clients without having to implement it?
This is because I have only seen examples where these endpoints are custom implemented.
My intention is to use jpa or jdbc implementation in the create client and create user endpoints.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO618.png)

i am going to store clients and users in a ddbb and i want to know if spring offers default endpoint to create clients and users, i have tried the example i have passed and others but they use manually implemented endpoints